# Getting images out of the system

Tags: file-uploads, database, file-manager

I updated ee to v2.10.1

I have an image with umlauts in the filename which I'm unable to remove.

- The .jpg file is not present, but still in the filemanager
- Synchronizing the upload folder doesn't remove it.
- recreating a fake file with the same name does nothing.
- Last idea is to delete the file by hand in the database with sequel pro.
- Since the file is added in an entry I can no longer edit the entry because I can't get past the file error message (Nice error handling by the way).

I've never made anything by hand in the db. Where do I find the images in the database?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started fine with the manual deletion; you just need to complete the process. Open your Edit form and find your entry_id. Then, go to your field groups and find the field_id of the file field. Then head to your channel_data MySQL table, find that entry_id (if your field_id is 10 and entry_id is 20, use `SELECT field_id_10 FROM exp_channel_data WHERE entry_id = "20";`), and clear out any value for that field.

**Edit** Ahh, a matrix field. That data is store in exp_matrix_data.

`SELECT * FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE entry_id = "20" AND field_id = "10";`

Find that row, and remove the sucker! You can drop the "field_id" requirement of that query if you're having trouble finding the row.

Comment: I found the entry but there is nothing image related.It is a matrix field.
`entry_id = 245` `field_id=72` But there is just "none" at this location. It is a matrix field. Is this located somewhere else than exp_channel_data?

Comment: I updated my answer, give it a try!

Comment: Word, thunderbird, glad to help!